# How to do about "array / list" in order to make "(int, list) -> float" in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this function:

```
def findScore(g):
    gLetter = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"]
    gPoint = [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]

    for i, v in enumerate(gLetter):
        if v==g:
            gp = gPoint[i]
    return gp
```

And I want to take number of subjects, then take grade letter of each by calling "findScore' and then return GPA by using one more fucntion like this:

```
def findGPA(n, list):
```

Noted:

1. number of subject (n) and a list of grade letters (list)"
2. findGPA() must call findScore() to turn each grade letter to grade point.

What is the function body ?

I want the output should be like:

```
>>> findGPA(3, ['A', 'B', 'C'])
3.0
>>> findGPA(4, ['B', 'B', 'C', 'B'])
2.75
'''
```

Comment: What is the first argument of `findGPA` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findGPA` doesn't actually *need* its first argument like you've proposed, because you could just find the length of the list of grade letters.

You can use your `findScore` function with a list comprehension to work out the score for each grade, and then sum these with the `sum` function. Finally, this is divided by the length of the scores list, found with the `len` function.

This can be done like so:

```
def findGPA(grades):
    return sum([findScore(x) for x in grades]) / max(len(grades), 1)
```

This then gives your desired output:

```
>>> findGPA(['A', 'B', 'C'])
3.0
>>> findGPA(['B', 'B', 'C', 'B'])
2.75
```

Comment: oh I just want to do some function more from the first argument

Comment: You _may_ want to divide by `max(len(grades),1)` to avoid a division by zero in case the array is empty.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks, I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary for the grade scores, then simply do lookups for each grade in the list passed in, sum the divide by the number of grades:

```
def  grd_dict():
    gLetter = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"]
    gPoint = [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
    return dict(zip(gLetter, gPoint))


def find_gpa(num, grds):
    scores = grd_dict()
    return sum((scores[g] for g in grds),0.0) / num
```

Output:

```
In [2]: find_gpa(4, ['B', 'B', 'C', 'B'])
Out[2]: 2.75

In [3]: find_gpa(3, ['A', 'B', 'C'])
Out[3]: 3.0
```

Personally I would do it all in a single function and just take a list of grades, you can get the number of subjects from the list passed in so num is not really needed.

A dict is the most efficient way to do your lookups but if you have to use lists maybe then you can use a the logic closely related  to an example in the [biect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#other-examples) docs:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def grade(g):
    g_point = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    grades = 'ABCDF'
    i = bisect_left(grades, g)
    return g_point[i]


def find_gpa(grds):
    return sum((grade(g) for g in grds), 0.0) / (len(grds) or 1)
```

`(len(grds) or 1)` will also handle an empty list:

```
In [44]: find_gpa(['F', 'F', 'F'])
Out[44]: 0.0

In [45]: find_gpa(['B', 'B', 'C', 'B'])
Out[45]: 2.75

In [46]: find_gpa(['A', 'B', 'C'])
Out[46]: 3.0

In [47]: find_gpa([])
Out[47]: 0.0
```

Using bisect you can search a sorted structure in `log(n)` time as opposed to potentially looking at every element.

Comment: Isn't better to combine both functions into one?...Is there any particular reason for having two besides OP design?

Comment: @IronFist, if you were repeatedly finding gpa's say in a loop for multiple users I would first call   `scores = grd_dict()` then for each user just use that dict, if it were one call per run I would just do it all in the one function. I only really used the two in this case to match the OP.

Comment: Just pass the list of grades g and use the len of g in place of num

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need two functions for this also you can completly remove the first argument to your `find_gpa` function and use the built-in [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function.

```
>>> gLetter = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"]
>>> gPoint = [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
>>> mapped_values = dict(zip(gLetter, gPoint))
>>> def find_gpa(score):
...     return sum(mapped_values[g] for g in score) / len(score)
... 
>>> find_gpa(['A', 'B', 'C'])
3.0
```

*If you are on Python 3.4 or newer* you can use the [`mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) function from the [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module.

Demo:

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> def find_gpa(score):
...     return mean(mapped_values[g] for g in score)
... 
>>> find_gpa(['B', 'B', 'C', 'B'])
2.75
>>> find_gpa(['A', 'B', 'C'])
3.0
```